# Improve performance of complex SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlperformance

Since a few month by now I am collecting data of football matches from open sources. To do so I grab the data of a specific website URL, that presents the data for a specific football match, with PHP via XPath. Then I do some data editing so they fit the way I need them. The next and last step is to transfer them into my MySQL database in several tables.

With a fast growing database I slowly run into severe performance issues. Because I do everything locally on my computer and that one isn't a monster of machine, it already takes some time to process a match. To get a feeling how fast that is: In the first days of datamining a match took around 24 seconds. However, now the average went beyond a 60 seconds threshold.

Up until now I occasionally went into the PHP code and tried to improve it where possible, because I thought the main issue is in not so clean code snippets. While it helped a bit, the average time grew further after several days and lately I started to realize there must be another time consuming issue. So I made a test PHP script that performes some kind of logging while running the main code.

It shows that some SQL queries I do to insert the data in my database tables take a lot of time on average (I analyzed 100 matches here):

- starting squad in DB: 6.44 seconds
- benched substitutes in DB: 8.49 seconds

Checking the queries again I realized they are quite complex.

Those are the tables involved:

**tblStartingSquad**

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+  
| id | matchID | player1ID | player2ID | player3ID | player4ID | player5ID | player6ID | player7ID | player8ID | player9ID | player10ID | player11ID | clubID |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
| 1  |    1    |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |     5     |     6     |     7     |     8     |     9     |     10     |     11     |   1    |
| 2  |    1    |    12     |    13     |    14     |    15     |    16     |    17     |    16     |    17     |    18     |     19     |     20     |   2    |
| 3  |    2    |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |     5     |     6     |     7     |     8     |     9     |     10     |     11     |   1    |
| 4  |    2    |    21     |    22     |    23     |    24     |    25     |    26     |    27     |    28     |    29     |     30     |     31     |   3    |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
```

**tblSubstitutes**

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+  
| id | matchID | player12ID | player13ID | player14ID | player15ID | player16ID | player17ID | player18ID | player19ID | player20ID | player21ID | player22ID | player23ID | clubID |
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| 1  |    1    |     32     |     33     |     34     |     35     |     36     |     37     |     38     |     39     |     40     |     41     |     42     |     43     |   1    |
| 2  |    1    |     44     |     45     |     46     |     47     |     48     |     49     |     50     |     51     |     52     |     53     |     54     |     55     |   2    |
| 3  |    2    |     32     |     33     |     34     |     35     |     36     |     37     |     38     |     39     |     40     |     41     |     42     |     43     |   1    |
| 4  |    2    |     56     |     57     |     58     |     59     |     60     |     61     |     61     |     62     |     63     |     64     |     65     |     66     |   3    |
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

**tblMatch**

```
+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
| matchID |         date        |    coach1   |      coach2      |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
|    1    | 2006-08-19 22:00:00 | Piotr Nowak | Fernando Clavijo |
|    2    | 2006-08-15 21:00:00 | Piotr Nowak |   Mustafa Ugur   |
+---------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

**tblPlayer**

```
+----------+------------------------+------------------+
| playerID |       namePlayer       |      short       |
+----------+------------------------+------------------+
|     1    |       Enis Ulusan      |    enis-ulusan   |
|     2    |   Grant Robert Murray  |   grant-murray   |
|     3    |     Evgeniy Shpedt     |  evgeniy-shpedt  |
|     4    | Mihai Alexandru Costea |   mihai-costea   |
|     5    |       Jan Zolna        |     jan-zolna    |
|     6    |    Adrian Gheorghiu    | adrian-gheorghiu |
|     7    | Marius Marian Croitoru | marius-croitoru  |
|     8    |    Jacov Nachtailer    | jacov-nachtailer |
|    ...   |          ...           |        ...       |
+----------+------------------------+------------------+
```

**tblClub**

```
+--------+-----------------+
| clubID |    nameClub     |
+--------+-----------------+
|    1   |   D.C. United   |
|    2   | Colorado Rapids |
|    3   | Caykur Rizespor |
+--------+-----------------+
```

And those are the queries involved:

**SQL Query starting squad**

```
$tblstarting_squad = 'INSERT INTO tblStartingSquad (matchID, player1ID, player2ID, player3ID, player4ID, player5ID, player6ID, player7ID, player8ID, player9ID, player10ID, player11ID, clubID) 
                    SELECT
                        (SELECT matchID FROM tblMatch WHERE date = "' . $match_date . '" AND coach1 = "' . $match_coach_home . '" AND coach2 = "' . $match_coach_away . '"), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[0] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[0] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[1] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[1] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[2] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[2] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[3] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[3] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[4] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[4] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[5] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[5] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[6] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[6] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[7] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[7] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[8] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[8] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[9] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[9] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[10] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[10] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT clubID FROM tblClub WHERE nameClub = "' . $match_club[1] . '" LIMIT 1)
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT e.matchID 
                        FROM tblStartingSquad As e
                        INNER JOIN tblMatch As m
                            ON e.matchID = m.matchID
                        WHERE m.date = "' . $match_date . '" AND m.coach1 = "' . $match_coach_home . '" AND m.coach2 = "' . $match_coach_away . '" AND e.clubID = (SELECT clubID FROM tblClub WHERE nameClub = "' . $match_club[1] . '")
                    );';

if (!mysqli_query($db_connection, $tblstarting_squad)) {
                    echo("Error description $tblstarting_squad: " . mysqli_error($db_connection) . "<br />");
                }
```

**SQL Query benched substitutes**

```
$tblsubstitutes = 'INSERT INTO tblSubstitutes (matchID, player12ID, player13ID, player14ID, player15ID, player16ID, player17ID, player18ID, player19ID, player20ID, player21ID, player22ID, player23ID, clubID) 
                    SELECT
                        (SELECT matchID FROM tblMatch WHERE date = "' . $match_date . '" AND coach1 = "' . $match_coach_home . '" AND coach2 = "' . $match_coach_away . '"), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[11] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[11] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[12] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[12] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[13] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[13] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[14] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[14] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[15] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[15] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[16] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[16] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[17] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[17] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[18] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[18] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[19] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[19] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[20] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[20] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[21] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[21] . '" LIMIT 1),
                        (SELECT playerID FROM tblPlayer WHERE namePlayer = "' . $player_name[22] . '" AND short = "' . $player_short[22] . '" LIMIT 1), 
                        (SELECT clubID FROM tblClub WHERE nameClub = "' . $match_club[1] . '" LIMIT 1)
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT e.matchID 
                        FROM tblSubstitutes As e
                        INNER JOIN tblMatch As m
                            ON e.matchID = m.matchID
                        WHERE m.date = "' . $match_date . '" AND m.coach1 = "' . $match_coach_home . '" AND m.coach2 = "' . $match_coach_away . '" AND e.clubID = (SELECT clubID FROM tblClub WHERE nameClub = "' . $match_club[1] . '")
                    );';

if (!mysqli_query($db_connection, $tblsubstitutes)) {
                    echo("Error description $tblsubstitutes: " . mysqli_error($db_connection) . "<br />");
                }
```

Both queries are practically identical. They insert the `playerID` of 11 (respectively 12) players into the `tblStartingSquad` (respectively `tblSubstitutes`) if there's no other entry with identical data. The `playerID` has to be checked beforehand in the database as the raw data doesn't have the individual ID. That happenes by selecting it via `namePlayer` and `short` from the table `tblPlayer`.

The tables `tblStartingSquad` and `tblSubstitutes` itself contain 110,000 rows (for 55,000 matches) currently, `tblPlayer` is at 100,000 rows.

I've googled a bit for solutions but wasn't quite able to find anything that would improve the overall speed. What I understand as an issue is that I have to check every player individually, so I get 11 and 12 subqueries. That's not really elegant, but I really don't have an idea how to improve that. Maybe someone out here on StackOverflow has a suggestion?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Added the 5 involved database tables to help understand the problem

Comment: @WilsonHauck it's just a local XAMPP server on my computer, not even a unix system. I'm working with 8 GB RAM. To everything else you requested I cannot provide answers as I don't know what you mean and want to know. I'm just a noob that is able to do some PHP and SQL and knows how to start XAMPP to get done what I want to do :)

Comment: @s1dy Reviewing your recent comments.  You have made GREAT progress from where you started.  When you are ready to tune your server for performance, please get in touch and you will be more amazed at the possibilities we can help you achieve by reducing wait time.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks, but no, thanks. I don't want to get in touch with you personally. I'm fine with the help I get by this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconsider your **wide** table design for a **long** table design. Numbered suffixed columns are never ideal data storage. Rows are cheap. Columns are expensive. Joins, aggregation, searching, indexing, etc. are much easier in long format. Otherwise, your queries will be complex as you show with 12 subqueries or even self-joins!

Interestingly, your *tblClub* and *tblPlayer* are in long format but not *tblStartingSquad* and *tblSubstitutes*! Simply, remove all extraneous player columns into **one** where rows indicate different players:

**tblStartingSquad**

```
 ID   MatchID   PlayerID    ClubID  
  1         1          5         1
  2         1          8         1
  3         1          9         1
...
```

**tblSubstitutes**

```
 ID   MatchID   PlayerID    ClubID
  1         1          2         1
  2         1         16         1
  3         1          7         1
...
```

**tblMatch** *(with renamed coach columns for clarity)*

```
ID                    Date      HomeCoach          AwayCoach
 1     2006-08-19 22:00:00    Piotr Nowak   Fernando Clavijo
 2     2006-08-15 21:00:00    Piotr Nowak       Mustafa Ugur
```

**PHP**

From this database design, you can then run a simpler PHP parameterized query call and even easier with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), instead of `mysqli` for binding many parameters from arrays.

```
// OPEN CONNECTION
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// SET PDO ERROR MODE TO EXCEPTION
$dbconn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// PREPARED STATEMENT
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblStartingSquad (`Match`, `PlayerID`, `ClubID`)
        SELECT m.MatchID, p1.PlayerID, c.ClubID
        FROM 
           (SELECT p.PlayerID
            FROM tblPlayer p
            WHERE p.namePlayer IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
           ) p1
        INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT p.PlayerID
            FROM tblPlayer p
            WHERE p.short IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
           ) p2 ON p1.PlayerID = p2.PlayerID
        CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT MatchID 
             FROM tblMatch
             WHERE `date` = ? AND HomeCoach = ? AND AwayCoach = ?) m
        CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT ClubID 
             FROM tblClub
             WHERE nameClub = ?) c
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
             (SELECT 1 FROM tblStartingSquad As e
              WHERE e.MatchID = m.matchID)"

try {
     // INITIALIZE STATEMENT
     $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);

     $params = array($player_name[0], $player_name[1], $player_name[2], 
                     $player_name[3], $player_name[4], $player_name[5], 
                     $player_name[6], $player_name[7], $player_name[8], 
                     $player_name[9], $player_name[10],  
                     $player_short[0], $player_short[1], $player_short[2],
                     $player_short[3], $player_short[4], $player_short[5], 
                     $player_short[6], $player_short[7], $player_short[8], 
                     $player_short[9], $player_short[10],         
                     $match_date, $match_coach_home, $match_coach_away, $match_club);

     // ITERATIVELY BIND PARAMS
     foreach($params as $key => $val) {
        $stmt->bindParam($key+1, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     }

     // EXECUTE ACTION
     $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Do a similar call for *tblSubstitutes*, adjusting append query's destination and `WHERE` clause and parameter values.

Comment: Awesome! I'll check that tomorrow and let you (and every other reader interested) know how much that will improve the performance!

Comment: After 5 days editing and changing the table structures (2,500,000 new rows were added) I was finally able to test the PHP code and its performance. The first issue I encountered was that `$stmt->bind_param` must be `$stmt->bindParam`. The next one is that the Script works without issues, but there's no entry made in the database and I can't find the reason why. I've changed everything that was necessary. Infact, if I use `$stmt->debugDumpParams()`to show me the prepared statement, it gives me `Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2` for every key position.

Comment: No exception was raised? Check Apache logs if running PHP on webserver. And make sure qmarks, `?` (which are a many here) equal the number in `$params` array. I do not know your setup so use this answer as guideline to actuals. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Ok, now the performance analysis: It went down from 14.93 s to 2.66 s. In total to the whole script performance that's an improvement of 24.8%. Not bad! I managed the PHP code to work by removing `foreach($params as $key => $val) {
        $stmt->bindParam($key+1, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     }` and changing `$stmt->execute();` to `$stmt->execute($params);`. That did it in the end. Don't ask me why :)

Comment: Well, glad to hear it all worked out. Performance likely is due to the redesign of table structure. Even with 2.5 million rows, databases scale better long than wide. There might even be another fast solution with `LOAD XML` allowing you to go straight from XML to database via PHP. I just answered a PHP-MariaDB [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335584/1422451).

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by O.Jones in the comments, it would be helpful to see more (php) code in order to judge on performance issues. 
Despite redesigning your database, another quick suggestion would in fact be to run a loop and use a [**prepared statement**](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for the individual querys for the playerIDs. That might give you a slight performance boost.

It does seem logically to me, to do more in PHP instead of outsourcing the logics of data fetching to SQL.

Comment: I edited my entry with more information. The whole PHP script itself has nearly no performance issues by now, I improved it as far as possible and it's overall at 3.x seconds in average for 1,570 lines of code. As mentioned I measured explicit tasks of the code and the values reflect the time that only the PHP-SQL-code quoted above needs. So it's really an SQL query issue. While I think the using of prepared statements is an idea I have to try, I actually don't see how it could improve performance since there're still several queries needed.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Prepared statements might help you to save on query parsing, data conversion and memory usage. As far as I understand you try to fetch similar data in one big query. Hence, instead you send a prepared statement to the database and inject different e.g. playerIDs within a loop. I have a strong feeling it will improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

The statements are not complex. They simply contain a lot of lookups. So make sure lookups are fast. You need the following indexes. Add them to your database if you don't have them already.

```
create index idx_find_player on tblplayer (nameplayer, short, playerid);
create index idx_find_club on tblclub (nameclub, clubid)
create index idx_find_match on tblmatch (date, coach1, coach2, matchid)

create index idx_find_squad1 on tblstartingsquad (matchid, clubid)
create index idx_find_squad2 on tblSsartingsquad (clubid, matchid)

create index idx_find_subs1 on tblsubstitutes (matchid, clubid)
create index idx_find_subs2 on tblsubstitutes (clubid, matchid)
```

I'm not sure which squad index is more likely to be used, so create both and see which the DBMS picks. You can then drop the other. Same for the substitutes Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

for an accurate answer we have to see your execution plan in SQL, send it here, so I can help you with your problem

before that, I think you are doing all wrong, instead of writing one select for the single row you can simply define user-defined-table in your database and pass your values. by doing that you could have better performance in your SQL and in your server-side code and I guarantee you, you have the best performance in the first level and after that as I said before need execution-plan

1. declare your type (don't forget to change datatype with your own)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[com_ListOfGuid] AS TABLE(NamePlayer NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,Short NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)

2. instead of creating select statement in your code just declare a datatable and fill data into it and pass it just like other parameters (don't forget to set you a name of column exactly like your user-defined-table-type )
   3.in your SQL code just join user-defined-table-type with your table and insert them into your target table (i give you an example and you change with your need)

   CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure_Your_Name
   @ObjectTable Type_Your_Name READONLY
   AS
   INSERT INTO TARGET_Table ()
   SELECT
       *
   FROM
       first_Table F INNER JOIN
       @ObjectTable T ON F.NamePlayer = t.NamePlayer and t.Short = f.Short